# Is it possible to flash or install stock Android on a smart watch?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, android-rom

I am looking to install stock Android (Lollipop/Marshmallow etc.) on my LG Watch Urbane. I cannot find any help on this since everywhere I search, I only get information about Android Wear.

I do not want Android Wear but a full, regular version of Android running on the watch. My main reason for doing this is to be able to *eventually* write my own personal custom Android ROM for the watch, but in order to start I want to see how regular Android will run on the watch.

I found that a CyanogenMod could be run on Samsung Galaxy Gear as demonstrated by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb0R_JeI6gg

Is there is strict specific hardware requirement to port Android (or even CM, misc. ROMs) on a smart watch? By this I mean, can I take any *off the shelf* smart watch and port Android to it? What steps do I need to take (like rooting, unlocking a bootloader etc.?)

Comment: Probably belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should also go ask this on [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/watch-urbane)